# Does echoing javascript always work in php?

Tags: php, javascript, echo

In php, if I put the following line

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>[javascript code here]</script>";
```

can I assume that the javascript code will be always be executed irrespective of where I put it in a php file?  Assume that the php syntax is valid and the line gets executed (it is not barred by some conditions)

Edit:  I have a php file where I have some javascript code and `alert('ok');` but the messagebox never appears. I was wondering if the code actually got executed and the browser dismissed the messagebox as the page was changed.

Comment: You are missing `";` at the end. Also why don't you just try it out ?

Comment: @HamZa I have a code where I have some javscript code and `alert('ok');` but the messagebox never appears. I was wondering if the code actually got executed and the browser dismissed the messagebox as the page was changed.

Comment: _"can I assume...irrespective of where I put it in a php file?"_ - No you can't assume this, because your PHP may have control structures such as `if` statements that prevent that line being executed.

Comment: You either have a syntax error, or you're doing some if/else statements which won't let you echo your JS code.

Comment: @nnnnnn ok, i meant provided that my php syntax is valid.

Comment: @InfMin is your code short? Maybe you can post a link to a dump of it (if it's not too long ofcourse)

Comment: So did I. If your PHP syntax is incorrect you've got even bigger problems... If you use your browser's "View Page Source" option do you see your JS code?

Comment: "as the page was changed" — Are you issuing a `Location` header?

Comment: @Quentin I have a large project and after my javascript code, it calls a function `redirect`. I don't know how that function works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

- You might put it in a PHP file that doesn't output HTML (e.g. a PDF document or a zip file).
- You might put it above a `header()` call and break the header
- You might put it inside an `if` statement body so it would only be included conditionally
- You might put it inside a `<style>` element, so it would be treated as invalid CSS
- etc

PHP just outputs *stuff*. If you want it to output a `<script>` element, then you have to put it somewhere where it will be output and it somewhere where outputting it makes sense.

Comment: you might want to add that he could've forgotten the php open and closing-tags `<?php ?>`.

Comment: +1, and the fact that a lot of people don't use javascript/disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will be executed because it is returned to browser as html code and browser does not care where it comes from. It is also often abused in XSS attacks.

To conclude it will execute always until it is correct JS and it prints in proper place in html structure.

Answer (score 0):

The code will be executed if the place in which it is inserted is valid. It will behave identically to if you had simply written the javascript code there.

For example, I'm sure the following code wouldn't work:

```
<ta<?php echo "<script type='text/javascript'>[javascript code here]</script>"; ?>ble>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are messing with two pairs of shoes here. Your javascript code **will not be executed anywhere** on the server side (where PHP is executed). After the PHP prozessor is done and the output (including your line of javascript) is send to the client your javascript will be executed. Depending on how strict the clients browser is your `<script>`-element needs to be inside of the `<head>` or `<body>` Element of your HTML-page

Comment: You messed up your answer, JS is also executed by browser.

Comment: thats what I wrote didn't I?